# input value to be different from what is sent to POST

Tags: php, html, forms, input

So the convention of using input type submit is this

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
```

this will give me a button that says "Submit" on it and inside the post array i will have

```
$_POST['submit'] = 'Submit'
```

is it possible to have the submit button to show Submit but have the post value to be different. In other words, I want a button that still says "Submit" on it but the

```
$_POST['submit'] = 1
```

Is this possible without JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks guys, both solutions work but I like dylan's solution slightly better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a hidden input field with the name 'submit' and set the value to 1. You don't have to set the value of the input button itself in order to capture this value.

Comment: this is not possible because i have multiple submit buttons, the user will press one of the submit buttons and the key for that submit will correspond to the value attached to the submit button that the user clicked.

Comment: but do each of these submit buttons have their own form? If so, it is possible. Are you using multiple submit buttons for one long form, then?

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this problem today. This works for me:

Instead of using `<INPUT>`, use `<BUTTON>`. You can specify `type=submit` in the same manner. However, the `<BUTTON>`'s display value is between `<BUTTON>` and `</BUTTON>`, and the `value=` value gets passed in the form.

I'm not sure if this is standard behaviour, but it works in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

From http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/type:

> The "submit" input  displays the text that you specify in the value attribute, but if no value is specified, the button face will simply display the word Submit.

You could register a click handler that changes the value to 1 when the form is submitted, e.g. something like

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" onclick="this.value=1;"/>
```

though an [unobtrusive handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) would be prettier.

**Edit** since you edited the question to ask for a non-JS solution, go with [Dylan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390691/input-value-to-be-different-from-what-is-sent-to-post/3390713#3390713)

Comment: can you give me the script that changes the value to 1?

Comment: do you think this is possible without javascript?